# PHP convert string to url code

Tags: php, parsing, markup

How can I convert a string like this:

`[link=http://stackoverflow.com, name=stackoverflow]`

to valid, semantic HTML markup such as

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>`

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bbcode.php

Comment: you can use a regular expression to read the url from the string and then put it into the anchor link format. Or i misread the question?

Comment: By parsing. With regular expression you will get into trouble as soon as its not well formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s*\[link=(.*?),\s*name=(.*?)\s*\]/', '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that regex:

```
$inputLink = "Here is a link to [link=http://stackoverflow.com, name=stackoverflow]";
$outputLink = preg_replace('/\[link=([^,\] ]+), name=([^\]]+)\]/','<a href="$1">$2</a>',$inputLink);
```